# Is the exponential of a linear operator T still a linear operator?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, matrix-exponential

Consider a linear operator $T: \mathrm R^n \rightarrow \mathrm R^n $.

Given:
$$
e^T = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{T^k}{k!}
$$
Is $e^T$ still a linear operator? If it is, why?

---

One should note that: Given a vector $v \in \mathrm R^n$, **the operator $e^T$ will take its effect by $e^T v$ instead of $e^{Tv}$**. And then this question will be solved by answers shown below.

## The origin and motivation of this question

I am reading a book about differential equation, and it claims this conclusion where I cannot find any clue.

Though I have finish a course on matrix theory and accept the fact that $e^T$ is a linear operator, I still cannot figure out why the product operator must be applied on $e^T v$ instead of $e^{Tv}$.

And now this question has been resolved: Because the exponential of a vector is not (well) defined by a sum of a serie, so we can only have a linear operator work in $e^T v$ fashion. I think it may revolve some confusions coming from beginners.

Comment: Yes, look at the right hand side as a definition of exponential. And note that $||AB|| <= ||A|| *||B||$, for any linear operators $A,B$. In particular, $||T^k|| <= ||T||^k$ which means that the series on the right converges in norm.

Comment: Thanks Salcio for your explanation! I totally agree with you, that this series is absolutely convergent and uniformly convergent. And my main question is how can $e^A$ being a linear operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^T$ is absolutely convergent by assumption (although it's easy to show). Let $F_m = \sum_{k=0}^m T^k/k!$ which is itself a linear operator since it's a finite-degree polynomial in the linear operator $T$. Then:

$$
\begin{aligned}
e^T v + e^T w &= \lim_{m \to \infty} F_m v + \lim_{m \to \infty} F_m w & \\
 &= \lim_{m \to \infty} (F_m v + F_m w) & \text{(by absolute convergence)} \\
 &= \lim_{m \to \infty} F_m (v + w) & \text{(by linearity of $F_m$)} \\
&= e^T (v + w).
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\begin{aligned}
a (e^T v) &= a \left( \lim_{m \to \infty} F_m v\right) & \\
 &= \lim_{m \to \infty} a (F_m v) & \text{(by absolute convergence)} \\
 &= \lim_{m \to \infty} F_m (av) & \text{(by linearity of $F_m$)} \\
&= e^T (av).
\end{aligned}
$$

The text alludes to the lines marked "(by absolute convergence)" when it says "by properties of limits".

Comment: Thanks Fred for fast response! It seems my question comes from the usage of operator $e^T$. In my opinion, the oeprator $e^T$ may work on a vector $v$ as $e^{T v} $ instead of $e^T v$. How can these two operations be distinguished? If it works in $e^{T} v$ this fashion, I agreewith your argument that $e^T$ is linear. ;-)

Comment: @XudongFeng $e^{Tv}$ would require you to take the exponential of a vector, because $Tv$ is a vector. As there is no way to take the power of a vector in a (Hilbert, Banach, what have you) space, the closest thing to multiplication being the dot product, it makes no sense to speak of powers of a vector. On the other hand, by definition the exponential of an operator is an operator, hence it should act on vectors "from the left" like any other operator. The fact that it is written $e^T$ is so you are sure it comes from exponentiation of $T$.

Comment: I think you are correct. the exponential of a vector doesn't make sense, which I now know from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923453/can-we-take-the-exponential-function-of-a-vector). And your induction about "the conventional usage of a operator to a vecotr" is convincing. Thanks Niki, solved.